# Understanding xsd:anyattribute tag with reference to mapping against SOAP xml message

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, xsd

I have a pretty basic question with regards to xsd:anyAttribute tag.

I am not able to understand the purpose of a xsd:anyAttribute tag in a SOAP message.

Suppose there is an XSD file which contains the following snippet:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Sibendu">
..........................
<xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
..........................
</xsd:complexType>
```

What is the purpose of such a anyAttribute tag when we are generating a SOAP message consisting of complex type named Sibendu?

Answer (score 1):

`<xsd:anyAttribute>` allows any attribute to be added to a complex type or attribute group. These attributes do not have to be defined in the schema to make the schema valid. That allow arbitrary extensions of types in a schema using attributes.

An in-depth documentation can be found here: [`<xsd:anyAttribute>` Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256443(v=vs.110).aspx). But to give a short summary:

The `namespace` attribute puts a restriction on those arbitrary attributes so that they must be originated from a given namespace. (`##other` is one of the special tokens that can be used here and specifies that attributes from any namespace that is not the target namespace of the parent element can be used).

The `processContents` attribute defines how the parser processes these attributes. `lax` means that the parser attempts to obtain the schema for the required namespaces and validates any attribute from those namespaces; however, if the schema cannot be obtained, no errors will occur. That's the setting in between `strict` (fail on validation errors) and `skip` (do no validation at all).

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Does this tag have any significance while defining data types with respect to the SOAP schema?

Comment: I'd say so. The type should be able to handle additional arbitrary properties  (gets more complicated when using namespace restrictions though, because these limit the arbitrary attributes to a defined set). Don't know if any of the interface code generators can handle such types, or they handle them.

Comment: It's often appropriate with XML to "ignore extensions that you don't understand". This anyAttribute declaration allows attributes such as @xml:id to appear on an element, but an application that isn't interested in this attribute should probably just ignore it.

Comment: @micheal : Well I am really not sure whether the application is interested or not.